# (React) locally shows mapped object in a list but after build, it doesn't show with no errors to diagnose the problem

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

Okay so, basically when I'm testing the project locally, it shows but when I build and deploy to Firebase it doesn't show.

The data is pulled from a JSON file and I'm mapping it to show the list of categories.

The JSON file:

```
[
    {
        "title": "Title1",
        "stack": ["React", "Firebase", "Styled Components"]
    },
    {
        "title": "Title2",
        "stack": ["Angular", "CSS", "HTML"]
    },
    {
        "title": "Title3",
        "stack": ["JavaScript", "VSCode"]
    },
    {
        "title": "Title4",
        "stack": ["Wordpress", "CSS", "PHP"]
    }
]
```

The component:

```
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import Projects from '../projects/projects.json';
import { v4 as uuidv4 } from 'uuid';

const CategoryList = () => {
    const [projects, setProjects] = useState(Projects);
    const [categories, setCategories] = useState();

    useEffect(() => {
        const categories = () => {
            let array = [];
            projects.forEach((project) => {
                array.push(...project.stack);
            });
            const uniqueCategories = [...new Set(array.map((stack) => stack))];
            setCategories(uniqueCategories);

        };

        return () => categories();
        // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
    }, []);

    return (
        <FilterContainer>
            <ul>
    {categories && categories.map((category) => <li key={uuidv4()}>{category}</li>)}
            </ul>
        </FilterContainer>
    );
};

export default CategoryList;
```

And I call the component to where it belongs.

So in local host it shows
[image]

but when I build and deploy it to Firebase it's blank

[image]

with no errors in the console.

I've tried to diagnose this issue by inserting console.log in the beginning and end of the useEffect hook and I noticed that the code wasn't getting executed..

So my question is, what do I need to search and study for? If it's a simple problem can someone point out the problem?

I've tried putting this straight into the .jsx file and also by making it as a component.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In development it works because react mount twice the component and doesn't work in production cause it mounts the component only one time (read [react-scrict-mode](https://reactjs.org/docs/strict-mode.html)). You call `categories` in the function that will be executed on component's unmount phase (read comments):

```
useEffect(() => {
    const categories = () => {
        let array = [];
        projects.forEach((project) => {
            array.push(...project.stack);
        });
        const uniqueCategories = [...new Set(array.map((stack) => stack))];
        setCategories(uniqueCategories);
    };

    // Here, if a useEffect hook returns a function
    // that function will be executed when the component is being destroyed
    return () => categories();
    eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
}, []);
```

To fix this, just remove the wrapper function and call your function like this:

```
useEffect(() => {
    const categories = () => {
        let array = [];
        projects.forEach((project) => {
            array.push(...project.stack);
        });
        const uniqueCategories = [...new Set(array.map((stack) => stack))];
        setCategories(uniqueCategories);
    };

    categories();
    eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
}, []);
```